# If condition between two date by hour

Tags: android, android-studio, date, datetime, if-statement

I'm makeing an app that want some text color Change when current time between 2 date.

like I have schedule with tasks, and from 1:00PM to 5:00PM there is a task I have to do.

Want to make a condition if current time between two date change the color of this text.

it's not just about color.

it's a lot of things put it's depend on this condition

Puted the two date in one TextView

```
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a")
    val time = simpleDateFormat.format(item.startDate) + "-" + simpleDateFormat.format(item.endDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like your `item.startDate` and `item.endDate` are `Date` instances. so you need also a `Date` with current time, which you can get with

```
val currDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

or even by creating new `Date` instance (is set to current by default)

```
val currDate = Date()
```

now you can convert `Date` to `long` timestamp

```
val startDateAsTimestamp = item.startDate.getTime()
val endDateAsTimestamp = item.endDate.getTime()
val currDateAsTimestamp = currDate.getTime()
```

and now your `if` would be

```
if (currDateAsTimestamp >= startDateAsTimestamp &&
     currDateAsTimestamp <= endDateAsTimestamp) {
```

Comment: Really appreciate your reply,

Comment: but there is an issue in this code
the value of timestamp it's not accurate
tred to print the vlues of every timestimp
but the ( currDateAsTimestamp ) time always the bigger one

Comment: so your `startDate` and `endDate` are pointing on past, `currDateAsTimestamp` is a "now" time (to be precise: the moment of executing constructors code). for obtaining current time you may also use `val currDateAsTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()`. and for checking your timestamps use any related site, e.g. [THIS](https://www.epochconverter.com/). be aware that some systems/frameworks/features are calculating timestamp in seconds (most) and some in millis (Android favor)